# Definition of trace and norm functions of an automorphism on an associative algebras.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory, automorphism-group

I encountered in the book: "Finite Geometry and Combinatorial Applications" the definition of `trace` and `norm` functions of an automorphism on a field $\mathbb{F}$ as follows:

Let $\sigma$ be an automorphism on $\mathbb{F}$ of the order $r$ (i.e. $\sigma^r = id$, where $id $ id the identity map).

The trace function of $\sigma$ is defined as
$$
Tr_{\sigma}(x) = x + \sigma(x) + \cdots + \sigma^{r-1}(x).
$$
Also, the norm function is defined as
$$
Norm_{\sigma}(x) = x\sigma(x)\cdots\sigma^{r-1}(x)
$$
for every $x \in \mathbb{F}$.

I am wondering if these functions are defined on automorphisms on associate algebras over a field in the same way.

Thanks.

Comment: This definition works for separable field extensions. In the general case of an associative algebra over a field, the trace resp. norm are the linear algebraic traces and determinants of the linear map $t \mapsto xt$.

Comment: @QiZhu Thanks, can you please provide a reference or a book?

Comment: Search for „field trace“ and „field norm“. Usually, the definition is first made for (arbitrary) finite field extensions but you can probably imagine why it works for algebras over a field.